# Using two conditions to write a conditional loop in Fortran

Tags: fortran, conditional-statements, logical-operators

Hoping someone could help me. I was just introduced to Fortran and can't seem to figure out why my code is producing an infinite loop.

I want to write a code that finds the root (c) of a function f(x)= x^3 - 3x - 4 between the intervals [2,3]:

I want the steps to be: initialize a and b.
Then calculate c = (a+b)/2.
Then if f(c) < 0, set b=c and repeat the previous step. If f(c) > 0, then set a=c and repeat the previous step.

The point is to repeat these steps until we get 1e-4 close to the actual root.

This is what I have written so far and is it producing an infinite loop.

I am also confused about whether it is a good idea to use the two condition loop (as in the function has to be greater/less than 0 .AND. absolute value of the function has to be less than 1e-4).

Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated!

MY CODE:

```
PROGRAM proj

IMPLICIT NONE

REAL :: a=2.0, b=3.0, c, f
INTEGER :: count1

c = (a + b)/2

f = c**3 - 3c - 4


DO
   IF (( f .GT. 0.0) .AND. ( ABS(f) .LT. 1e-4)) EXIT

   c = (a+c)/2
   f = c**3 - 3c - 4
   count1 = count1 + 1

    PRINT*, f, c,count1
END DO

PRINT*, c, f

END PROGRAM proj
```

I want to be able to show the iterations and print each step (getting closer to the actual root).

Comment: I would separate the conditionals. IF(F(C)<0 THEN, B=C, CYCLE. And also the IF(… <1.0E-4) EXIT. You probably want to initiate count to 0.
For debug if count >100 EXIT.

Answer (score 0):

What you have described is the bisection method for localizing a zero
of a function in the interval [a:b].  There are three possibilities.

1. The interval does not contain a zero.
2. An endpoint of the interval is a zero.
3. There are more than one zero in the interval.

This program implements bisection where a number of subintervals
are inspected.  There are other, and better, methods but this should
be understandable for you.

```
!
! use bisection to locate the zeros of a function f(x) in the interval
! [a,b].  There are three possibilities to consider:  (1) The interval
! contains no zeros;  (2) One (or both) endpoints is a zero; or (3)
! more than one point is a zero.
!
program proj

   implicit none

   real dx, fl, fr, xl, xr
   real, allocatable :: x(:)
   integer i
   integer, parameter :: n = 1000

   xl = 2                     ! Left endpoint
   xr = 3                     ! Right endpoint
   dx = (xr - xl) / (n - 1)   ! Coarse increment

   allocate(x(n))
   x = xl + dx * [(i, i=0, n-1)]    ! Precompute n x-values
   x(n) = xr                        ! Make sure last point is xr
   !
   ! Check end points for zeros.  Comparison of a floating point variable
   ! against zero is exact.
   !
   fl = f(xl)
   if (fl == 0) then 
      call prn(xl, fl)
      x(1) = x(1) + dx / 10         ! Nudge passed xl
   end if
   fr = f(xr)
   if (fr == 0) then 
      call prn(xr, fr)
      x(n) = x(n) - dx / 10         ! Reduce upper xr
   end if
   !
   ! Now do bisection.  Assumes at most one zero in a subinterval.
   ! Make n above larger for smaller intervals.
   !
   do i = 1, n - 1
      call bisect(x(i), x(i+1))
   end do

   contains
      !
      ! The zero satisfies xl < zero < xr
      !
      subroutine bisect(xl, xr)
         real, intent(in) :: xl, xr
         real a, b, c, fa, fb, fc
         real, parameter :: eps = 1e-5
         a = xl
         b = xr
         do
            c = (a + b) / 2
            fa = f(a)
            fb = f(b)
            fc = f(c)
            if (fa * fc <= 0) then        ! In left interval
               if (fa == 0) then          ! Endpoint is a zero.
                  call prn(a, fa)
                  return
               end if
               if (fc == 0) then          ! Endpoint is a zero.
                  call prn(c, fc)
                  return
               end if
               !
               ! Check for convergence.  The zero satisfies a < zero < c.
               !
               if (abs(c - a) < eps) then
                  c = (a + c) / 2
                  call prn(c, f(c))
                  return
               end if
               !
               ! Contract interval and try again.
               !
               b = c
            else if (fc * fb <= 0) then   ! In right interval
               if (fc == 0) then          ! Endpoint is a zero.
                  call prn(c, fc)
                  return
               end if
               if (fb == 0) then          ! Endpoint is a zero.
                  call prn(b, fb)
                  return
               end if
               !
               ! Check for convergence.  The zero satisfies c < zero < b.
               !
               if (abs(b - c) < eps) then
                  c = (b + c) / 2
                  call prn(c, f(c))
                  return
               end if
               !
               ! Contract interval and try again.
               !
               a = c
            else
               return   ! No zero in this interval.
            end if
         end do
      end subroutine bisect


      elemental function f(x)
         real f
         real, intent(in) :: x
         f = x**3 - 3 * x - 4
      end function f

      subroutine prn(x, f)
         real, intent(in) :: x, f
         write(*,*) x, f
      end subroutine prn
end program proj
```